# SQL insertion syntax error. Taking value as field

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have written the following SQL command to create a database, then create a table and then add data to the created_db.created_table.

However it seems to be wrong. Since SQL takes the values as the fields name. What is the problem with it?

I also use Microsoft SQL server 2012 Enterprise Edition.

```
CREATE DATABASE dbsample;
CREATE TABLE passwording (
     passwording_id INT
     ,passwording_username VARCHAR(256)
     ,passwording_date INT
);

INSERT INTO passwording (passwording_username, passwording_date) VALUES("myUserName", 754254354);
```

And the error I'm getting:

```
Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 11
Invalid column name 'myUserName'.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

remove " in `"myUserName"` use `'myUserName'`

```
INSERT INTO passwording 
        (passwording_username,passwording_date) 
VALUES ('myUserName',754254354);
```

[**Working Fiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/f512a)

Answer (score 1):

In your table, you have specified datatype `INT` for column `passwording_date`. But you have entered value as `25/12/2011` which is a string. Would that work? You should have used [Date](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187752.aspx) datatype right?

**EDIT**: With reference to your updated question, why use `""` to insert a string value to your table. Your query should rather be

```
INSERT INTO passwording (passwording_username, passwording_date) VALUES('myUserName', 754254354);
```

Answer (score 1):

The passwording_date is defined as a INT instead of a DATE data type.  This will cause a conversion failure message.  Also, the passwording_id is not being set in your code.  You may want to specify identity.  Finally, the date format is in a British style, so you may want to explicitly cast it to a datetime data type with the corresponding style.

Here's a revised version of the code:

```
CREATE TABLE passwording (
     passwording_id INT IDENTITY(1, 1) NOT NULL
     ,passwording_username VARCHAR(256) NOT NULL
     ,passwording_date DATE NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO passwording (passwording_username, passwording_date) VALUES('myUserName', CONVERT(DATETIME, '25/12/2011', 103));
```

Comment: this is not the solution. take a look at the question (updated)

Answer (score 1):

Use `single quote` instead of `double quotes` for `myUserName`

Now u can run below query

```
CREATE DATABASE dbsample;
CREATE TABLE passwording (
     passwording_id INT
     ,passwording_username VARCHAR(256)
     ,passwording_date INT
);

INSERT INTO passwording (passwording_username, passwording_date) VALUES('myUserName', 754254354);
```

Answer (score 0):

INSERT INTO passwording
VALUES ('myUserName',754254354);